# Java extending class types

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, collections

I have the following code snippet which returns a type mismatch error:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public Map<String, Class<? extends SomeClass.SuperClass>> subClass() {
    return Collections.singletonMap("hello", SomeClass.SubClass.class);
}
```

The class declaration looks like the following:

```
public class SomeClass {

    public static abstract class SuperClass { }

    public static class SubClass extends SuperClass{ }
}
```

This returns a type mismatch error, stating:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<String,Class<SubClass>> to Map<String,Class<? extends SuperClass>>
```

Why is this occurring? Regardless of whether I use "? extends SuperClass" or just "SuperClass" in the parameterized return type of subClass(), I still see this same error. I've also tried just extending SomeClass instead but that hasn't worked either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `SubClass` is subtype of `SuperClass`, but `Map<String, Class<SubClass>>` isn't subtype of `Map<String, Class<SuperClass>>`. For more information you can see [Generics, Inheritance, and Subtypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html)

For Java SE 7 you can use:

```
return Collections.<String, Class<? extends SomeClass.SuperClass>>singletonMap("hello", SomeClass.SubClass.class);
```

Comment: Explicit type parameter is a good point, can Java 8 be calling that automatically?

Comment: This are [Type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) and [Target Typing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#target-typing) stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a typo. It should be:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public Map<String, Class<? extends SomeClass.SuperClass>> subClass() {
        return Collections.singletonMap("hello", SomeClass.SubClass.class);
    }
```

You missed `.class` :)

---

In Java, generics are invariant. This means if:

`Dog` extends `Animal` then `List<Dog>` **does not** extend `List<Animal>`

```
List<Animal> ls = new ArrayList<Dog>() //illegal
```

Hence this is invalid code and doesn't work:

```
Map<String, Class<SomeClass.SuperClass>> hello2 = Collections.singletonMap("hello", SomeClass.SubClass.class);
```

And this is perfectly alright:

```
Map<String, Class<? extends SomeClass.SuperClass>> hello = Collections.singletonMap("hello", SomeClass.SubClass.class);
return hello;
```

Comment: That still gives the Type mismatch error in Netbeans.

Comment: I am using Java8. And it compiles fine on mine.

Comment: I have Java 7 (1.7.0_67)

Comment: So is this only a Java 8 feature? I'm looking into it

Comment: I read the Java 8 whats new page but did not see anything new that might cause this. I thought it might be Netbeans so compiled with javac and Ideone, both did not compile.

Comment: It is the better type inference now that is responsible. Check this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html